# How many co-prime pairs are there between 1 and N?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I suspect it's $$n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i) + 1$$ with $\phi(i)$ being the Euler function for the number of co-primes to $i$ between $1$ and $i$. But I have absolutely no proof to this but for example it stands for 8.

Comment: $\sum_{i\le n} \phi(i)$ is asymptotically about $3n^2/\pi^2$, so your sum is approximately $0.7n^2$, but the true value is closer to $0.6n^2$.  Did you try it for $n < 8$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the number is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \phi(i)$ why? how many pairs have $i$ as the largest number? there are $\phi(i)$ . Classifying over the largest number in the pair we get the answer.

If you wanted ordered pairs the answer is $2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \phi(i)-1$ since each one must be counted once more except for $(1,1)$

Comment: It's funny how counting this for 8 completely mislead me. And yes, I was thinking ordered.